# ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomObjectScope' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils'

Tags: python, jupyter

```
[ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomObjectScope' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzTpI.png)

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 3
      1 import cv2
      2 from keras.models import load_model
----> 3 from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope
      5 from models.unets import Unet2D
      6 from models.deeplab import Deeplabv3, relu6, BilinearUpsampling, DepthwiseConv2D

ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomObjectScope' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils' (C:\Users\xinai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py)
```

I've been trying to code this on Python but this Import Error keeps on popping up.

Comment: how did you `pip install` keras ?